# how to copy php file multiple file name using php?

Tags: php

i want to copy same php file using php , working with copying one file, I can copy one file , but I have problem when copying multi files using array.

```
$copys = file('copy.txt');

foreach($copys as $copy) {
copy('page1.php', '$copy');
}
```

copy.txt is name files:

```
page2.php
page3.php
page4.php
```

i want to copy page1 to page2, page3, page4 ,..  page100

But this code not work !

Could you give me a solution :(

Thanks for any help !

Comment: `copy('page1.php', $copy); //<--remove single quotes around $copy`

Comment: @vallez did you try my answer?

Comment: @Steve you should post that as an answer

Comment: @steve working.. but files create to txt not php

Comment: output "page2.php.txt" ,"page3.php.txt" ,"page4.php" . only page4 make to php file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to generate a specific number of copies and the numbers for the new file names you will have to use a for loop

```
<?php
    $master = 'page1.txt';
    $copy_to = 'page%d.txt';
    $num_copies = 10;

    // start you rloop at 2 so we start copying to `page2.txt`
    // and dont overwrite page1.txt
    for ($i=2; $i < $num_copies+2; $i++) {
        copy($master, sprintf($copy_to, $i));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
$copys = arary('from.txt'=>'to.txt', 'from2.txt'=>'to2.txt');

foreach($copys as $from => $to) {
   copy($form, $to);
}
```

Or if you want to copy the same file multiple times

```
$copys = file('copy.txt');

foreach($copys as $to) {
   copy('page1.php', $to.".php");
}
```

Comment: @downvoter whould you mind leaving a comment why did you vote?

Comment: page1.php is master file , i want to copy / duplicate this to page2.php, page3.php , not to txt file

Comment: this shouldn't copy to txt files, it depend on the content of copy.txt file

Comment: copy.txt content is just name file , i want to copy or duplicate content from  page1.php to page2, page3, page4,...

Comment: In your question you said `copy.txt is name files:

page2.php
page3.php
page4.php` so it has .php extension!